# Creating views or facets search with multiple flags

Tags: flags

So I'm categorising with flags and I will have over 20 per node so that multiple people can flag a node with their opinion... Searching for the past two weeks I have found it hard to work out how I put these flagged results on to the front end, in search, making multiple flag recipes (to show to searchers), with views?

My first question is, do I have to make a view for every single flag I have on the front end? There are over 20 of them, I don't mind doing this but can't this be put in to an exposed view or something so I can have one view with all outputs covered?

How can I mix up certain flags together/make recipes so that if I wanted three certain flags together so that people can search through that output I could, can I do this in views with flags?

My final question is, how do I put the output of a search or a view I make and make it sortable by how many times that node has been flagged with that flag or combination of different flags? If someone wants to see the nodes all flagged with 'river' and that the nodes that come to the top of the search/output/view has had it's 'river' flag flagged by more users than those below it. This will show that that node is definately more 'river' than the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I add all of the flags (each one individually) as a relationship, so I end up with 20+ relationships, I can expose each one in a field to visitors and that way they can click through what type of flags they want to see and don't.

It's not pretty, you will end up with 20+ true/false select boxes but its working.